# C++ serialization of data-structures

Tags: c++, file, serialization, boost

I'm studying serializations in C++. What's the advantage/difference of `boost::serialization` if compared to something like:

```
ifstream_obj.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj), sizeof(obj)); // read
// or
ofstream_obj.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj), sizeof(obj)); // write
// ?
```

and, which one is better to use?

Comment: Your samples just do not work for objects holding (non POD) or referencing (e.g. via pointer) other objects

Comment: This is highly dependent on the the data structure.

Comment: Essentially these samples are as bad as a memcpy on classes

Comment: @alexj123 See the 1st comment Dieter Lücking provided.

Comment: @alexj123 I just realized your "why?" question might have been to  Dieter Lücking's first comment but I had assumed it was for the second comment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big advantages of Boost Serialization are:

- it actually works for non-trivial (POD) data types (C++ is not C)
- it allows you to decouple serialization code from archive backend, thereby giving you text, xml, binary serialization
- If you use the proper archive you can even have portability (try that with your sample). This means you can send on one machine/OS/version and receive on another without problems.

Lastly, it adds (a) layer(s) of abstraction which make things a lot less error prone. Granted, you could have done the same for your suggested serialization approach without much issue.

Here's an answer that does the kind of serialization you suggest but safely:

- [How to pass class template argument to boost::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523771/how-to-pass-class-template-argument-to-boostvariant/27526407#27526407)

Note that Boost Serialization is fully aware of bitwise serializable types and you can tell it about your own too:

- [Boost serialization bitwise serializability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121545/boost-serialization-bitwise-serializability)

Comment: Are you referring with this advantages to my examples(write,read) in the question?...

Comment: @alexj123 What else?

Comment: actually you are talking about `boost::serialization`, aren't you? I thought my examples were valid for "little" projects(for programs which don't do nothing of particular).

Comment: Me too. Also, this answers your question: _"I'm studying serializations in C++. What's the advantage/difference of boost::serialization if compared to something like: [...]"_. There are cases where you *might* get away with what you had, but be sure to do it safely (see the first linked answer)